# Python Datetime - How do I only get the time to print and not the date? How do I configure it to make sure it only prints what I want it to?

Tags: python, datetime, module, configuration

Trying to figure out how to configure the datetime to only print what I want it to print. I only want it to print time and don't know how to stop it from printing date.

Since it is a module, I don't know where to begin.

My Code:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.now()

print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Current output: 2019-06-02 00:39:54.896889

Expected output: 00:39:54.896889 (And maybe not even '896889')

Comment: You should read about `strftime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Documentation of strftime: [Link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)